# Ng test ignores --environment flag after update to Angular6 and Karma 1.7.1

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular6

After upgrading to Angular 6 and Karma 1.7.1 the command `ng test --environment=test` no longer takes the `--environment` flag into account and always runs with the values for dev (from `environment.ts`).

Is anyone aware of how to fix this?
Also the `singleRun: false` from `karma.conf.js` is no longer respected and the browser closes instantly when it finishes.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "meteor-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/sass",
                "node_modules"
              ]
            },
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/sass/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ng2-toasty/style-material.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "meteor-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "browserTarget": "meteor-app:build:test"
            },
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "meteor-app:build:staging"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "meteor-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "meteor-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/sass/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ng2-toasty/style-material.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
              }
            ],
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "meteor-app-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "meteor-app:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "meteor-app",
  "cli": {
    "warnings": {
      "typescriptMismatch": false
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "swc",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "swc"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I believe there is an issue with the angular Cli because creating  a new application and running `ng test --prod` which is a shorthand for `ng test --configuration=production` fails and I believe it must work out of the box.

I have solved this by using the following `fileReplacements` in the `angular.json` configuration though I consider it a workaround rather than a proper solution:

```
 "test": {
            ...
            "fileReplacements": [
              {
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
              }
            ],
          }
```

Hope it helps others having the same issue.